# How to fix huge sized utf-8 emoji icons in Awesome WM?

Tags: utf-8, fonts, x11, emoji, awesome-wm

I want to set the utf-8 "icons" as the taglist headers, but this "icon" turns out to be huge (upper left). I tried changing theme font and font size, but it did not bring any result. Current font: "Ubuntu 10".

[image: Huge utf8 symbol size]

Tell me please, what should I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vaguely remember hearing about this problem before on the `#awesome` IRC channel. The reason there was that the person had configured FontConfig not to scale fixed size fonts. I do not remember the details, but the first Google result lead me to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/font_configuration#Disable_scaling_of_bitmap_fonts.

Comment: Thanks! I use Gentoo and try this: 

spc ~ # eselect fontconfig list | grep bitm
  [7]   10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf
  [21]  25-ttf-arphic-uming-bitmaps.conf
  [88]  70-no-bitmaps.conf *
  [89]  70-yes-bitmaps.conf
  [96]  85-wqy-bitmapsong.conf
spc ~ # eselect fontconfig enable 7   

Now the font is displayed correctly